# Google Script .getRange skipping first row of data

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having an odd issue with a script I'm implementing to copy one column of data to another column. Here's the code:

```
function copySavedtoPlan() {
  var TeamSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Team Selector - BattlePlan');
  TeamSheet.getRange(7,3,50).copyValuesToRange(TeamSheet,2,2,7,56);
```

The column to copy contains a set of values pulled in via HLOOKUP from another sheet, and is either text or blank:

```
7    *P1 JTR
8    *P1 JTR
9
10   P1 Droids
11
12   *P1 JTR
13   P1 Rebels
14   *P1 JTR
```

The result of the function skips the first row and transposes other rows:

```
7
8    *P1 JTR
9
10   P1 Droids
11   *P1 JTR
12
13   P1 Rebels
14   *P1 JTR
```

Row 7 was skipped and row 11 was swapped with row 12.  Any ideas what's going on here?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code. Anything else you'd like to mention?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, dumb question here; but are you following the documentation with respect to "getRange" and "copyValuesToRange":

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)
```

Also, from the documentation:

> If the destination is larger or smaller than the source range then the
>   source is repeated or truncated accordingly.

Again, sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: `Sheet#getRange` takes between 1 and 4 parameters